# Area of a circle inside a quarter circle

Tags: geometry, circles, area, tangent-line

I'm trying to figure out a couple things. The main question I have is how to find the area of a circle inscribed inside a quarter circle with a radius of x. The secondary question to that is if the radius of the inner circle drawn to touch the tangent lines of the sides of the quarter circle bisects the sides of the quarter circle. I hope that makes sense...

Comment: <irrelevant> I asked myself this question a few years ago and wasn't able to figure it out ever since - seeing it here is quite the pleasant surprise. </irrelevant>

Comment: There's no like button here, so I'll just comment to say it. I'd wager there was a stick that became dislodged from your brain today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A figure helps a lot.  The three segments labeled $r$ are all radii of the small circle. The diagonal of the square is $r\sqrt 2$, so $r(1+\sqrt 2)=x$  No, the tangency points do not bisect the radii of the big circle, they cut them in ratio $1: \sqrt 2$

[image]

Comment: A figure is good for sure. I'm new to this forum, so I don't really know how to add pictures. So, where does the "1" come from in the "r(1+sqrt(2))"

Comment: @Joseph, the $r(1 + \sqrt(2))$ comes from the $r \sqrt{2}$ needed to cross the square and the additional $r$ needed to get to the edge of the circle (going perfectly NE/SW)

Comment: x is equal to the radius of the small circle plus the diagonal of the square.

Comment: The radius of the quarter-circle, $x$, is equal to the diagonal of the square plus the radius of the small circle, which is $r\sqrt{2}+r$. This factors to $r(1+\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Simple factoring. Silly me, lol.

Comment: @Joseph: to add a picture you click on the picture icon in the add question or answer page.  It may take a bit more reputation than you have to post one.  It lets you bring over pictures from the web or upload from your computer.  I know it accepts JPEG and GIF.

Comment: Hi Ross, 
Sry for bringing up an old question but I have a doubt. How do we know that the diagonal extended from the square is going to touch the circle exactly at the point where it making contact with the bigger circle. I can see that symmetrically, but can we prove that in some way?

Comment: @Bootstrap:  it is symmetry.  If you continue the diagonal radius, you have two congruent setments of a circle.